# Rails polling with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, long-polling

I have an index page that lists all users and their statuses (available or unavailable), every user can change his/her status anytime. What I am trying to do is real-time polling to display the most up to date statuses. I have done the Jquery polling function and it works (tried it with a simple alert and it displays the alerts every 10 seconds). Now I don't know what to include in my index.js.erb file, that code that's supposed to refresh the div that includes the users and their statuses. I have this :

```
$("#users-container").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render @users) %>")
```

To replace the old users and theirs statuses with the new newer ones, but this is not working, the page is not changing at all.

Any suggestions?

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<div id="users-container">
  <%= render @users %>

</div>
```

_user.html.erb

```
<p> 
    <%= name_with_status(user.full_name, user.status, user.id) %>
    </p>
```

Where name_with_status is just a helper that displays the name, status.

Comment: I don't think you want `replaceWith` because you don't actually want to replace your `#users-container` element, you want to replace its contents. `$("#users-container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @users) %>")` would do.

Comment: @ChristianVarga I tried that but still the page doesn't update automatically!

Comment: That's why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer. Regardless, you'll want to use `.html()`.

Comment: @ChristianVarga it worked! you are right, I just had small typo but .html() worked. Please add answer so I can accept

Comment: Ah that's good to know. I didn't actually think it would solve your problem; just thought it would be a good tip. Glad to see it worked, answer has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()`. In your case, you want to replace the contents of `#users-container`, but not the entire element itself.

So you can do something like this:

```
$("#users-container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @users) %>")
```